# problems with adding images to a box2d body

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i added this code to my file

```
CCSprite *_ball;
_ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"A.jpg" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_ball.position = ccp(20, 20);
[self addChild:_ball];

b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
ballBodyDef.position.Set(20/PTM_RATIO, 20/PTM_RATIO);
ballBodyDef.userData = _ball;
_body = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

b2CircleShape circle;
circle.m_radius = 30.0/PTM_RATIO;

b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
ballShapeDef.friction = 0.2f;
ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.8f;
_body->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef
```

it runs but it doesn't show the image A.jpg. why this?

Answer (score 0):

Box2D has nothing to do with a sprite being displayed or not.  You have a bug somewhere else.  Maybe "self" is not being drawn or _ball is nil?